# AngularJS error ng areq not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, metadata

I'm trying to make my meta controller to dynamically change the meta tags, but in console i get `error ng areq not a function`. I searched through StackOverflow for similar problems but none of the solution is for my problem. I have these tags in my HTML:

```
    <html  ng-app="WebApp" >
    <head  ng-controller="MetaDataCtrl">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ meta.tags.description }}">
</head>
<body >

    <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
var app = angular.module('WebApp', [
  'ngRoute'
]);

/**
 * Configure the Routes
 */
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routes, $location) {
 $location.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
  $routes
    // Home
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html",  
      controller: "PageCtrl",
      metadata: {
           title: 'This is my title',
           description: 'This is Desc.' }

    })
}]);

app.controller('PageCtrl', function (/* $scope, $location, $http */) {

});

.controller('MetadataCtrl', function ($scope, metadataService) {
   $scope.meta = metadataService;
});
```

Comment: Can you put code of metadataService

Comment: I don't have any code for it. I compiled the code from various tutorials on net. Do i need code, i thought angular handles metadata services.

Comment: What's your build process? Do you minify your code?

Comment: angularjs is minifed version if you ask that but it's simple code.

Comment: AngularJS has no `metadataService` out of the box. You need the code, your you'd have to reimplement it yourself.

Comment: Is there any tutorial to do it, because I'm beginner in this and it was a feat of will coming this far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such service `metadataService` and you don't defined it yourself. However, looks like you just need to accecc current route `metadata` object. In this case it's quite easy to do as it's part of the `$route` service. you should also set up a listener to update global `meta` object when route changes:

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {
        $rootScope.meta = current.metadata;
    });
}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/nQfqNWvoYQQElv909uZF?p=preview

Comment: True, but i need to bind them to title, description etc  and make google bots see them as such in fetch tab. That is why i opted for this way to improve SEO.

Comment: So what's the problem: `$scope.meta = $route.current.metadata`.

Comment: I wrote it but it doesn't change anything. Do i need something additional?

Comment: @user3187715 You actually need to set up a event listener to update meta object. Check update answer and demo.

Comment: You gave me corect answer but anyway for SEO doesnt work. Google bot still sees it as 

     <title>{{ meta.title }}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ meta.description }}"

Comment: Yes, I believe you will need to do something more advanced also, like creating HTML snapshots using some automated tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94186/discussion-between-user3187715-and-dfsq).